# Tomcat-users.xml is rewritten on container restart - how do I supply credentials?

Tags: maven, cargo

Im using cargo to deploy a war file to a tomcat server. I'm unable to login to the manager however as conf/tomcat-users.xml is rewritten when I start the container ie

```
mvn cargo:run
```

how I can supply user/password creds to access the manager?

cheers!

**Edit**: Cargo configuration

```
<plugins>
    <!-- Start's the plugin tag for Cargo! -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <wait>false</wait>
  <container>
    <containerId>tomcat${tomcat.major}x</containerId>
    <zipUrlInstaller>
      <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${tomcat.major}/v${tomcat.version}/bin/apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}.tar.gz</url>
      <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extract/</extractDir>
      <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/download/</downloadDir>
    </zipUrlInstaller>
    <output>${project.build.directory}/tomcat${tomcat.major}x.log</output>
    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
  </container>
  <configuration>
    <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-${tomcat.version}/container</home>
    <properties>
      <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
      <cargo.servlet.port>9080</cargo.servlet.port>
      <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>9008</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>start-container</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>start</goal>
      <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <deployer>
        <deployables>
          <deployable>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod-war</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <pingURL>http://localhost:9080/mod-war</pingURL>
            <pingTimeout>30000</pingTimeout>
            <properties>
              <context>mod-war</context>
            </properties>
          </deployable>
        </deployables>
      </deployer>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>stop-container</id>
    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>stop</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Could you supply some details of how you've configured the cargo plugin? Admittedly the documentation isn't great, but it's not completely clear from your question whether you're using cargo to run an embedded instance of tomcat or whether you're deploying to a remote instance of tomcat.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, brand new at cargo plugin .. this config above deploys a fresh tomcat 7 container to the target folder on the maven project.  I've also found a [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/CARGO/Custom+File+Configurations) which I'll try also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You can supply custom configuration through the following xml (link to cargo docs in the above comments)

```
      <files>
        <copy>
          <file>tomcat-users.xml</file>
          <tofile>conf/tomcat-users.xml</tofile>
          <configfile>true</configfile>
          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        </copy>
      </files>
```

So you can specify your own conf/*.xml or anything else and it will be copied before the container starts. I can login to the manager now :)

Cheers